# Property 'object' does not exist on type 'Database'

Tags: angular

Estoy intentando recibir el usuario de un archivo login.components.ts usando el siguiente codigo

`this.email = this.loginForm.value.email.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.]+/g,'').replace(/\./g,'');
      this.password = this.loginForm.value.password;
      let loginUser = "/usuarios/${this.email}"
      const user = this.db.database.object(loginUser);`

pero me aparece al compilar con ng serve, me aparece `Property 'object' does not exist on type 'Database'.`

El database que estoy utilizando es `angularfire2`

Cual podria ser la solucion para este error?

Comment: Que libreria estas usando para `Database` ?

Comment: Estoy usando angularfire2

Comment: no debería ser `this.db.object(loginUser);` ?

Comment: ahorita intentare solo hacerlo asi LPZadkiel